# Ninject dynamic multiple constructor arguments

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ninject

I have been implementing Dependency Injection into an existing Winforms project and it has been going well so far, however I want to generalise the calling of the Forms, specifically the varying quantity of constructor parameters.

My code is as follows:

```
Public Shared Function GetForm(formObject As BaseObject, _
    parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As Form

        Select Case formObject.GetType()
            Case GetType(Production.Task)
                Return SMKernel.Kernel.Get(Of Forms.Production.Domain.ManageTask) _
                    (New Parameters.ConstructorArgument() _
                    {New Parameters.ConstructorArgument("task", _
                        CType(formObject, Production.RequiredTask))})
        End Select

    End Function
```

This works fine, the interface(s) are injected correctly, the constructor parameter "task" is populated and the Form works as expected.

As you can see I have a Dictionary that can contain several parameters which I need to add to the `ConstructorArgument` part of the `Get` method. Looking at the IntelliSense, I should be able to pass in an array of `ConstructorArgument` objects, however no matter what I have tried, it doesn't seem to work for one reason or another.

How do you accomplish this in Ninject if it is at all possible. If this way isn't possible, how can you pass multiple parameters into a Form's constructor via Ninject?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is the dictionary actually a set of ctor argument names and their values? So this is actually an ultra dynamic factory?

Comment: Your right, the dictionary does contain a set of constructor argument names and values, this is what the `ConstructorArgument` object takes. I just want to pass an array of these objects into the `Get` method, which according to intellisense you can, but I haven't managed to get it to work for some reason, therefore I was hoping someone with more experiance in Ninject that me could point out what (probably small) mistake I am making here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the already provided ResolutionExtensions

```
    public static T Get<T>(this IResolutionRoot root, params IParameter[] parameters)
```

Then combine it with LINQ

```
Kernel.Get(parameters.Select(kvp => new ConstructorArgument(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToArray())
```

Provide more details and we might give you are more elegant approach.

Comment: I will try this later when I am on my development machine, but it looks good from here. Thanks.